# Can Azure DevOps build variable Build.Reason be used in YAML template compile time conditions?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I would like to have something like this:

```
  - ${{ if or(eq(parameters.RunTestsOnPRBuildOnly, false), eq(variables.Build.Reason, 'PullRequest')) }}:
      - template: ps-module-run-tests.yml
```

This does not work, as `variables.Build.Reason` is empty. Is it possible at all?

Note that I know how to modify the `ps-module-run-tests.yml` template to express my desire as a runtime condition. In other words I know how to arrive at this:

[image]

What I am curious is whether `Build.Reason` can be used in a compile time condition, so that these steps are not even rendered. On the surface, there is no inherent problem with that, because the value is known right at the start, but it depends on when the template is compiled. If too early, then it is impossible, but I am unaware of such details. Maybe I cannot do it, because I am missing something.

So, is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
variables.Build.Reason
```

try to use

```
variables['Build.Reason']
```

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services
Build.Reason is available in template expressions at compile time

I have looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion there is one example also there is note that if you want to use property dereference syntax it can contain only
[image]
and so dot sign is not acceptable (dot between Build and Reason)

Comment: I will test it, but could you point where in the documentation it is said?

Comment: It does work. Please, include the quote from the document.

Comment: I have looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion there is one example also there is note that if you want to use dereference syntax it can contain only [a-Z 0-9 and _ ] and dot sign is not acceptable (dot between Build and Reason)